# Web Application - Read USB Token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, usb

I am developing a website using ASP.NET MVC 4, for security reasons only a few computers can login.

And recently I saw this video showing a USB token login:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9z1xkng3FQ&feature=relmfu

My question is, how can my application I read data from USB?

Comment: Refer to [Javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885) provided by free Signer.Digital Browser Extension.

Answer (score 3):

You need some kind of browser plugin or or application on the client pc.

Another idea is to store a key on a stick which simulates a keyboard and types the key into the website.

When you use a commercial token like "eToken" they come with the needed tools.